# Is there any difference between the "for" and "as" keywords in the loop macro?

Tags: common-lisp

In Common Lisp, in the loop macro, the **and** and **as** keywords appear to function identically:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 3 do (print i))
(loop as i from 1 to 3 do (print i))
```

Is there some subtle difference I'm missing? If not, why bother with two different yet identical keywords?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[6.1.2.1 Iteration Control](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_aba.htm):

> The `for` and `as` keywords are synonyms; they can be used interchangeably. ... By convention, `for` introduces new iterations and `as` introduces iterations that depend on a previous iteration specification.

E.g.:

```
(loop for x from 1 to 10
  as x2 = (* x x)
  as x4 = (* x2 x2)
  for y from 10 downto 1
  as y2 = (* y y)
  as y4 = (* y2 y2)
  sum (* x4 y4))
```

Why?!

Tradition! :-)

And, also...

> "... a computer language is not just a way of getting a computer to perform operations, but rather ... it is a novel formal medium for expressing ideas about methodology"
>   Abelson/Sussman "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs".

IOW, we write code for people (including you 6 months from now) to read, not just for computers to execute.

Everything that makes your code more readable is "fair game".

Comment: Aaand now I have the song from "Fiddler on the Roof" stuck in my head.

Comment: how about an example?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: is it good enough now? or did you have in mind a "read life example" from an actual project?

Comment: @sds: no, that's a perfectly fine example. Thank you!